# Assign variable from one asp to other asp page

Tags: asp.net, vbscript, asp-classic

I have to asp pages, on selector change i send ajax to other asp page and want to get back variable from that asp page.

index.asp

```
<div  id="ExSearch" name="ExSearch" >
<script>

$(function() {   
    $('div.selector select').on('change', onValueChange);
    var sIndex = 2;
    var Vb_sIndex;
    Vb_sIndex = <%=Vb_sIndex_geted%> ' How to do that?
    function onValueChange() {      
      sIndex = sIndex + 1;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Functions/ExSearch.asp',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'startIndex=' + sIndex + '',
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#ExSearch").html(data);
            }
        });
    };
});

</script>
<%= Vb_sIndex%>
```

ExSearch.asp

```
<% Vb_sIndex_geted = Request.form("startIndex") + 1
     Response.Write = Vb_sIndex_geted ' for first click it = 4,how to assign this value to index.asp?
%>
```

How to set Vb_sIndex in index.asp from ExSearch.asp ?

Comment: Ofcourse i tryed and got Vb_sIndex = empty always

Comment: Yes axaj populate div with received info in html format

Comment: You are not passing it in your Ajax Function,
try data: 'startIndex=' + Vb_sIndex  + '',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX runs client-side *after* ASP has processed all of your `<%...%>` sections, so you can't return a value from AJAX into a server-side variable (without some additional work, anyway).

Also, you're mixing client-side and server-side code in your example. `Vb_sIndex` is declared in your client-side jQuery function but you're attempting to use it in a server-side ASP tag: `<%= Vb_sIndex%>`. This isn't going to work. When ASP processes `<%= Vb_sIndex%>`, you'll either get an error (if `Option Explicit` is declared) or an empty value (if not).

If you want to assign the return value of your AJAX call to a server-side variable, consider creating and submitting a form in your AJAX `success` function, passing `data` as a hidden form variable. Something like this should work:

```
$.ajax({
    ....
    success: function (data) {
        $('<form method="post" action="index.asp"><input type="hidden" name="h" value="' + data + '"></form>').appendTo('body').submit();
    }            
}
```

Then when your page is reloaded, you can pull the value out of your `Form` collection:

```
<%
    Dim Vb_sIndex
    Vb_sIndex = Request.Form("h")
%>
```